# How to deal with Menus that extend below screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a difficult time handling menus/submenus/sub-sub menus that extend below my screen using the hover action.

I have a menu that has multiple layers of sub menus. The menu is expanded using HOVER. There are some instances where the sub menus or sub sub menus extend below my screen. If I move the cursor to scroll the screen, the menu collapses. The only way I can get to the menu items is to use the down arrow while keeping my cursor in the menu. Not ideal. I want to be able to have the menu scroll or have the window scroll or something that allows me to access the hidden menu items.

```css
/*Menu Color Classes*/

.green {
  background: #6AA63B;
}
.yellow {
  background: #FFFF00;
}
.red {
  background: #CC6666;
}
.purple {
  background: #CC99FF;
}
.siteblue {
  background: #0047FF;
}
.blue {
  background: #0292C0;
}
.purplered {
  background: #66FFFF;
}
.yellowgreen {
  background: #99FF33;
}
.orange {
  background: #FF9900;
}
.bluegrey {
  background: #669999;
}
#main_nav {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0
}
#main_nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
  text-align: center;
}
#main_nav ul a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  font-family: HelveticaNeue, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
#main_nav ul li,
ul li ul {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: black;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
}
#main_nav ul li ul li {} #main_nav > ul > li > a,
h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#main_nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
}
#main_nav ul ul ul {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
}
#main_nav ul li:hover {
  background: gray;
}
#main_nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#main_nav ul li.current-menu-item {
  background: #999
}
#main_nav ul ul li {
  float: none;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
}
#main_nav ul ul a {
  line-height: 120%;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
#main_nav {
  margin-top: 1px;
}
​
```

```html
<nav id="main_nav">
  <ul class="siteblue">

    <li class="green">
      <a id="close" href="" onclick="showiframe(this.id); return false;">ITEM</a>
      <ul class="green">
        <li class="green"><a id="busdev" href="" onclick="showiframe(this.id); return false;">About</a>
        </li>
        <hr/>

        <li class="green">Item</li>
        <hr/>
        <li class="green">Item</li>
        <hr/>
        <li class="purplered">Item
          <ul class="green">
            <li class="green">Item</li>
            <hr/>
            <li class="green">Item</li>
            <hr/>
            <li class="green">Item</li>
            <hr/>
            <li class="green">Item</li>
            <hr/>
            <li class="green">Item</li>
            <hr/>
            <li class="green">Item</li>
            <hr/>
            <li class="green">Item</li>

            <hr/>
            <li class="green">Item</li>
            <hr/>
            <li class="green">Item</li>
            <hr/>
            <li class="green">Item</li>
            <hr/>
            <li class="green">Item</li>
            <hr/>
            <li class="green">Item</li>
            <hr/>
            <li class="yellowgreen">Item
              <ul class="green">
                <li class="green">Item</li>
                <hr/>
                <li class="orange">Item
                  <ul class="green">
                    <li class="green">Item</li>
                    <hr/>
                    <li class="green">Item</li>
                    <hr/>
                    <li class="yellow">Item
                      <ul class="green">
                        <li class="green">Item</li>
                        <hr/>
                        <li class="green">Item</li>
                        <hr/>
                        <li class="green">Item</li>
                        <hr/>
                        <li class="green">Item</li>
                        <hr/>
                        <li class="green">Item</li>
                        <hr/>
                        <li class="green">Item</li>
                        <hr/>
                        <li class="green">Item</li>
                        <hr/>
                        <li class="green">Item</li>
                        <hr/>
                        <li class="green">Item</li>
                        <hr/>
                        <li class="green">Item</li>

                        <hr/>
                      </ul>

                    </li>
                    <hr/>
                    <li class="green">Item</li>
                    <hr/>
                    <li class="green">Item</li>
                    <hr/>
                  </ul>
                  <li class="green">Item</li>
                  <hr/>
                  <li class="green">Item</li>
                  <hr/>
                  <li class="green">Item</li>
                  <hr/>
              </ul>
              <li class="green">Item</li>
              <hr/>
              <li class="green">Item</li>
              <hr/>
          </ul>
          <li class="green">Item</li>
          <hr/>
          <li class="green">Item</li>
          <hr/>
      </ul>
      </li>


  </ul>
</nav>
​
```

Comment: At this point I would say reconsider having nested submenus so large that they extend past the viewport

Comment: Instead of positioning the submenu's top at the same height as its parent element, align it with the top of the parent's menu. Or if that's too high, position the submenu's bottom with the bottom of the parent element.

Comment: Seems like a tree picker would be easier to use than that menu system; one little mouse jitter and you're back at stage 1.

Comment: You should take a step back and re-think your menu system. I menu that is that long and only appears when you hover makes for a bad user experience

Comment: Management is set on HOVER, at least at this point. Is there a way to build this so that each menu appears horizontally below the one above it. Building from the menu that was hovered to the left back to the left side of the first menu item before building to the right?